# Nullable type in generic method

Tags: dart

I'm learning Dart, and I'd like to have a method similar to `let` in Kotlin.

I'd like to use it as:

```dart
var variable = ...;// nullable type, for example MyClass?
var test1 = let(variable, (it) => 'non null: ${it.safeAccess()}');
// test1 type is String?
var test2 = let(variable, (it) => 'non null: ${it.safeAccess()}', or: () => 'Default value');
// test2 type is String since either way we return a String
```

In this example, the variable is a nullable instance of `MyClass` and the output is a nullable String if no fallback is provided, or a non-null String if a non-null fallback is provided.

Here's the prototype I have written:

```dart
typedef O LetCallback<I, O>(I value);
typedef O OrCallback<O>();

O let<I, O>(I? value, LetCallback<I, O> cb, {OrCallback<O>? or}) {
  if (value != null) {
    return cb(value);
  }
  if (or != null) {
    return or();
  }
  if (null is O) {
    return null;
  }
  throw Exception("Please provide a default non-null value");
}
```

Dart complains I can't return null, but I don't understand why it's illegal. I had expected this (in explicit syntax):

```dart
var variable = ...;// nullable type, for example MyClass?
var test1 = let<MyClass, String?>(variable, (it) => 'non null: ${it.safeAccess()}');
// I=MyClass, O=String?
var test2 = let<MyClass, String>(variable, (it) => 'non null: ${it.safeAccess()}', or: () => 'Default value');
// I=MyClass, O=String
```

In my expectation, the compiler would infer the type `O` as either `String?` or `String`, so that `return null` is legal only if `O` is nullable.

It seems that using the generic syntax, the types referenced are always non-nullable. Is that so? Is it a limitation of the language? Is it possible to write what I want to achieve, or am I forced to have two implementations? (like `let` and `letNotNull` for example)

---

edit: after writing this, I tried the two implementations route. Here's what I have written:

```dart
typedef O LetCallback<I, O>(I value);
typedef O OrCallback<O>();

O letNonNull<I, O>(I? value, LetCallback<I, O> cb, OrCallback<O> or) {
  if (value != null) {
    return cb(value);
  }
  return or();
}

O? let<I, O>(I? value, LetCallback<I, O> cb, {OrCallback<O>? or}) {
  if (value != null) {
    return cb(value);
  }
  if (or != null) {
    return or();
  }
}
```

For some reason, this is legal:

```dart
var test = letNonNull(null, (it) => "whatever", () => null)
```

I had expected that the `() => null` callback would be a compiler error, since `O` can't be null (as per my initial observation: I can't return null).

It seems like the null-safety is not fully enforced.

edit2: it seems it's legal only if the type is inferred. E.g.:

```dart
letNonNull(null, (it) => "bogus", () => null); // legal
letNonNull<String, String>(null, (it) => "bogus", () => null); // illegal
```

I had hoped that the inferred types would be non-null...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return `null` because `O` can, potentially, be bound to a non-nullable type.
Type variables are not "always non-nullable", but they are always *potentially* non-nullable. What you return from a function with return type `O` must be valid for *all possible* bindings of `O`, even when it's bound to non-nullable types. Or when it's bound to `Never`. That means that the only type that can possibly be valid to return is `O` itself, and `null` does not have type `O`.

If you want to always be able to return `null`, you must make the return type of `let` be `O?`. That makes it always nullable, even when `O` itself is not nullable.
In that case, I'd restrict `O` to be non-nullable by giving it a bound of `extends Object`.

The alternative, as you then do, is to return `null` if `null` is a valid return value, and throw if it's not (and thereby avoid having to return anything, since you have nothing to return), but your approach doesn't work with the type system.
Try changing

```dart
 if (null is O) {
    return null;
  }
```

to

```dart
  O? nullReturn = null;
  if (nullReturn is O) {
    return nullReturn;
  }
```

As stated above, the only type you can return is `O`, so you want the value `null` to have type `O`. You can either do `if (null is O) return null as O;` (or even just `return null as O;` and rely on the `TypeError` from the cast istead of throwing yourself), or you can use type promotion like this example to avoid the extra `as`.

You probably also want to restrict `I` to be non-nullable using a bound, and then use `I?` for the argument to `let`, but not to `cb`. That ensures that the inferred `I` type is always non-nullable.

```dart
O let<I extends Object, O>(
    I? value, 
    O Function(I) cb, 
   {O Function()? or}) {
  if (value != null) {
    return cb(value);
  }
  if (or != null) {
    return or();
  }
  O? returnNull = null;
  if (returnNull is O) {
    return returnNull;
  }
  throw ArgumentError.value(null, "or", 
      "Please provide a default non-null value");
}
```

The `letNotNull` would also need to put a bound on the type variables:

```dart
O letNonNull<I extends Object, O>(
    I? value, O Function(I) cb, O Function() or) {
  if (value != null) {
    return cb(value);
  }
  return or();
}
```

The reason

```dart
var test = letNonNull(null, (it) => "whatever", () => null)
```

is valid is that it infers `letNotNull<Object, String?>`, and

```dart
letNonNull<String, String>(null, (it) => "bogus", () => null); // illegal
```

is invalid because the type for `O` is not nullable.

The type system doesn't known how that `or` function argument is going to be used, it just checks that its a proper subtype of the `O Function()` parameter type for the actual value of `O` that is supplied.
The type checking of the function body ensures it can only be used in positions where the result is acceptable. That's the type checking which disallowed returning `null` above because that check has to work for *all* types that `O` can be bound to.

I'd consider defining the `let` operation as an extension method instead, because then it does type inference on the value first, before looking at the callback. Something like:

```dart
extension Let<T extends Object> on T? {
  R let<R>(R Function(T) callback, {R Function()? or}) {
    var self = this;
    if (self != null) return callback(self);
    if (or != null) return or();
    R? nullReturn = null;
    if (nullReturn is R) return nullReturn;
    throw ArgumentError.notNull("or");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I tried to use your `let` implementation which is cleaner, I see you use `Function` which is better than my type definitions. However, when I invoke `let(whatever, (it) => doSomething(it))` with `void doSomething(Whatever w)` (e.g. non nullable argument), the compiler says that `it` is nullable. I had assumed that it would not, since the type of the callback is `O Function(I)`, neither type is nullable. What works though is `let<Whatever, void>(whatever, (it) => doSomething(it))`. I had hoped that the inferred types would be enough.

Comment: Here's what I have: https://dartpad.dev/e53713a8453b5aeb9b7972dc6d0c2d4c?null_safety=true

Comment: That's a failure of inference. You can see that where you write `let<A, void>(...)` it works. I can't say right off the bat why it fails, but if you write `(A it) => ...` then it also works, so somehow it fails to deduce that `it` must be an `A`, even though you call `test(it, ...)`.

Comment: I added an example of how to declare `let` as an extension method. With that, you can write `x.let((it) => ...)` without problems. (You could get the same effect by currying the function as `R Function<R>(R Function(T), {R Function()? or}) let<T extends Object>(T? value) => <R>(R callback(T), {R or()?}) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about extensions (I'm really learning lol). Thanks for all the time taken to help me understand.

Comment: Your extension is almost flawless, except when `R` is `void`. Is there a way to detect that and not throw the exception?

Comment: What is the problem with `R` being `void`? It should just work as any other type, and without an `or` argument, it should use the `nullReturn is R` branch. 
The way to detect it, if you really want to, would be `if (T == typeof<void>())` (where `typeof` is declared as `Type typeof<T>() => T;`, and is used because `void` cannot be used as a type literal directly).

Comment: I don't know what I did, indeed it _is_ flawless. Thanks again, I didn't know about `typeof`. I learned a great deal about Dart thanks to you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I found it. Here's my test plan and the first test fails: https://dartpad.dev/866de31720b6e7970f73b9fdaa50597b?null_safety=true — I also didn't manage to use typeof, I tried `if (nullReturn is R || R == typeof<void>())` but it is not accepted because the extension is on a nullable type. This is also a failure of the type system in my opinion, because a null check is done first and the code is not reachable if `T?` is null.

Comment: OK sorry for the spam. It fails because my closure return type is not void, so it expects a `or` closure. If my test is `aNull.let(() { x = y; /* no return */ })` then it works.

Comment: Indeed, `=> x = y` returns the value of `y` and gets a type inferred. Also `aNull.let((it) => "bogus");` infers a type argument of `String`, which is why it needs an `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
return null as <The type you want>
```